# What is the issue with random variable Z?

Tags: probability, random-variables

When opening a container of $32$ toy ballet dancers performing pirouettes, let random variable $X$ denote the number of broken dancers,
and let random variable $Y$ denote the number of whole (unbroken) dancers.
Write random variable $Z = X/Y$ , i.e., $Z$ is the ratio of broken dancers to whole dancers.
What complication arises in this definition of $Z$ as a random variable?

So my work: X and Y are clearly discrete random variables with $X \in \{0,1,2,...,32\}$ and  $Y \in \{0,1,2,...,32\} $

But wouldn't $Z$ be just another discrete random variable? with $Z \in \{0, 1/31, 2/30,..., 1\}$?

With no issue?

My question is What's the Issue with $Z$? I'm not seeing it. Can someone help me see the issue?

Thank You!

Comment: What if $Y= 0$?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be, all broken toys then? $X = 32$ and $Y=0$, what's the issue? The ratio is just $1$ to $0$, right?

Comment: Oh wait, I see it, it's undefined, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises for when $Y=0$, since $X/Y$ becomes undefined there.

Of course, as you have seen, there is a natural way to maintain things by defining $Z$ through $X/Y$ for $Y \ne 0$, and then adding in the $1$ afterwards to handle the skipped case. For instance, take

$$Z \in \left\{ \frac{32-y}{y} \; \middle| \; y \in Y \setminus \{0\} \right\} \cup \{1\}$$

But if we very literally define $Z$ as all of the fractions $X/Y$, then we have a problem. A little subtle, but a problem nonetheless.

---

*Mostly reposting what I did in the comments with a little elaboration, for the sake of giving this question a "proper" answer and keeping it out of the unanswered queue on the site.*